# python compare lists and return unmatched values

Tags: python, comparison

I want to compare sublists of my list and return the unmatched variables

input is

```
lst = [['2','b'], ['!d','e'], ['s','f', 'd'], ['24','!b'], ['and','7']]
```

desired output

```
out_lst = [['2','b'],['!d','e'],['s','f','d'] ['24','!b'], ['and', '7']['e','s','f'] ['2','24']]
```

I am comparing my sublists with each other and if I find d in one sublist ['s', 'f', 'd'] and !d in another sublist ['!d', 'e'], I merge both and add only the unmatched variables that is ['e', 's', 'f'] as another sublist at the end of the list. How can it be done efficiently?

```
import itertools
def reduction(self):
      for i in range(0,len(self.lst)):
          for j in range(0,len(self.lst[i])):
              if not any(x in [i][j]== "!"+x in [i][j]):
                  self.new_lst.append()
              else:
                  itertools.chain(x , ~x)
                  self.new_lst.pop()
 print new_lst.reduction()
```

I get errors because of matching a list with a string. Is there a better way of implementing this logic?

Comment: What is returned by `your_function([['a', 'b', '!c'], ['!a', '7', 'c']])`?

Comment: You should describe both your desired output and the undesired output produced by your code. As is, your post doesn't ever clearly ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
def reduction(self):
    res = self.lst[:]
    for i in self.lst:
        for j in i:
            for k in self.lst:
                if "!"+j in k:
                    temp = i[:]
                    temp.remove(j)
                    temp2 = k[:]
                    temp2.remove("!"+j)
                    res.append(temp2+temp)
                    self.lst = res[:]
    return self.lst
```

Comment: thanks but your code works for only one instance.                             `Enter input:   a.x.!a+b.!c+d.c+2.!k+k.h`

  which is represented as
`[['b', '!c'], ['d', 'c'], ['2', '!k'], ['k', 'h']]`                                                                                                               output based on your code
`[['b', '!c'], ['d', 'c'], ['2', '!k'], ['k', 'h'], l['b', 'd']]`                                                                                                                  I get an output like this, if I give 2 instances. I should get `['2','h']` too